# How to add manual values to Row[] in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, row

In my application, i need to create one Row[] and have to add some values to that Row[].

i created Row[] like below:

```
Row[] r = new Row[5];
```

Now i need to add some random values like `"sydney", "[]", "atlanta",10,40` to `r`
any idea how to add those values?

Comment: What is `Row` ?

Comment: Row is nothing but a result which can coming from spark dataframe

Answer (score 3):

you can create Row by calling Rowfactory.create

```
Row row = RowFactory.create(1,2,"str");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` then it is an interface.

See this Documentation : [Row (Spark 1.4.0 JavaDoc)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html)

Def:

```
public interface Row
extends scala.Serializable
```

You cannot create objects by using new operator on interfaces so that's **NOT** possible.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html):

> To create a new Row, use `RowFactory.create()` in Java or `Row.apply()` in Scala.